# Recording with AMD proprietary drivers

Tags: graphic-drivers, kernel, release-loki, amd

I had issues taking screenshots till I stumbled upon someone suggesting alt+ctrl+f2 and then alt+ctrl+f7 to make it where you can take screenshots. Which worked for screenshots. I tried doing this for video with OBS when recording EVE Online.  I got the audio but black screen for video.
I cannot use the open source xorg.conf drivers currently because I cannot adjust resolution nor get my display to extend to my second monitor.  Its stuck in mirror at a resolution only good for my smaller screen 2nd monitor.

I have been doing some reading and wonder if upgrading the kernel or moving to Loki would resolve the gpu driver issues I am having?

Comment: Loki and kernel 4.4 do not support the FGLRX drivers.And what hardware do you have , I have the same problem and my laptop is an HP Pavilion g7 2269wm with AMD A8-4500M and integrated Radeon HD 7640G discrete class GPU

Comment: I have R9 380 Tonga chipset with FX 3870 CPU